# How much its important for a JS developer to know CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, layout

I am good in Javascript and angular stuff and found it very much interesting but bad in CSS and designing a layout of the page.I can't simply design a page.I dont found interest in CSS stuff.I want to be a SPA developer but is it possible without mastering CSS?Whenever i got a task related to Javascript,i have to face css/stylesheets.How much its important for a JS developer to know CSS?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? "Whenever i got a task related to Javascript i have to face CSS/stylesheets". If you keep running into it, what do you think the prudent thing to do is? Ignore it and pretend it doesn't exist?

Comment: @mason got the point.now let me search how to master css

Comment: just copy and alter the bootstrap component markup and use http://bootswatch.com/ to make it look decent without much skill at all.

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between learning the CSS language and being able to design a nice looking SPA or website. I myself am very good with CSS, but can't design a nice layout. That's why I work with graphic designers, who can provide me with a PSD or image that I can use to translate into CSS for the web.

If you're a JS developer, you should pick up the CSS language very quickly, as frameworks like JQuery are based on the CSS syntax for their DOM selector syntax.

You can use a framework like Twitter Bootstrap as a base for your layout and go from there. Having a head start in designing your SPA by using a framework can be really helpful.

So to answer your question: it's very useful to know CSS as a JS developer and you probably know more than you think. On the other hand, not very many JS developers are also good graphic designers!

Comment: Very true. graphic designers are more inclined into "art" rather than technical stuffs like coding, although they have base knowledge about html structures. its the front-end developer responsibility to convert that "art" into a real web layout using HTML,CSS, Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

from my experience css is critical.
you can't develop a page with JS alone. you must add the HTML/CSS.
Doesn't mean you are a UX expert and that you decide how the page looks like, but to develop it, its a lot of css work.
css becomes easier with time, and i mostly learned it by playing with the values in chrome developer tools to see how different attributes/values change my layout and style of the UI.
don't ignore css. its a must have in your skill set as a web developer.